# How to convert HTML table with select and input to json and back again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following html table, which has rows and columns that each contain a td with text, a select and a input[type='text'].  There is also a last td on each row for removing rows from the table and is irrelevant to saving the table rows as json and can be ignored.

```
   <table id="columnsTable" class="table white-table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column</th>
            <th>Condition</th>
            <th>Value</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="columnsTableBody">
        <tr id="StudentInfo.FirstName" class="StudentInfo.FirstName" name="StudentInfo.FirstName">
            <td>FirstName</td>
            <td>
                <select id="StudentInfo.FirstName-condition">
                    <option value="LIKE">CONTAINS</option>
                    <option value="=">EQUALS</option>
                    <option value="!=">NOT EQUAL</option>
                    <option value="&gt;">GREATER THAN</option>
                    <option value="&lt;">LESS THAN</option>
                    <option value="&gt;=">GREATER THAN OR EQUAL TO</option>
                    <option value="&lt;=">LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO</option>
                </select></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="StudentInfo.FirstName-value" class="required" title="Value is required"></td>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="StudentInfo.FirstName-checkbox"></label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="StudentInfo.LastName" class="StudentInfo.LastName" name="StudentInfo.LastName">
            <td>LastName</td>
            <td>
                <select id="StudentInfo.LastName-condition">
                    <option value="LIKE">CONTAINS</option>
                    <option value="=">EQUALS</option>
                    <option value="!=">NOT EQUAL</option>
                    <option value="&gt;">GREATER THAN</option>
                    <option value="&lt;">LESS THAN</option>
                    <option value="&gt;=">GREATER THAN OR EQUAL TO</option>
                    <option value="&lt;=">LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO</option>
                </select></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="StudentInfo.LastName-value" class="required" title="Value is required"></td>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="StudentInfo.LastName-checkbox"></label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="StudentInfo.CurrentCollege" class="StudentInfo.CurrentCollege" name="StudentInfo.CurrentCollege">
            <td>CurrentCollege</td>
            <td>
                <select id="StudentInfo.CurrentCollege-condition">
                    <option value="LIKE">CONTAINS</option>
                    <option value="=">EQUALS</option>
                    <option value="!=">NOT EQUAL</option>
                    <option value="&gt;">GREATER THAN</option>
                    <option value="&lt;">LESS THAN</option>
                    <option value="&gt;=">GREATER THAN OR EQUAL TO</option>
                    <option value="&lt;=">LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO</option>
                </select></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="StudentInfo.CurrentCollege-value" class="required" title="Value is required"></td>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="StudentInfo.CurrentCollege-checkbox"></label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="StudentInfo.EmailAddress" class="StudentInfo.EmailAddress" name="StudentInfo.EmailAddress">
            <td>EmailAddress</td>
            <td>
                <select id="StudentInfo.EmailAddress-condition">
                    <option value="LIKE">CONTAINS</option>
                    <option value="=">EQUALS</option>
                    <option value="!=">NOT EQUAL</option>
                    <option value="&gt;">GREATER THAN</option>
                    <option value="&lt;">LESS THAN</option>
                    <option value="&gt;=">GREATER THAN OR EQUAL TO</option>
                    <option value="&lt;=">LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO</option>
                </select></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="StudentInfo.EmailAddress-value" class="required" title="Value is required"></td>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="StudentInfo.EmailAddress-checkbox"></label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="StudentInfo.Status" class="StudentInfo.Status" name="StudentInfo.Status">
            <td>Status</td>
            <td>
                <select id="StudentInfo.Status-condition">
                    <option value="LIKE">CONTAINS</option>
                    <option value="=">EQUALS</option>
                    <option value="!=">NOT EQUAL</option>
                    <option value="&gt;">GREATER THAN</option>
                    <option value="&lt;">LESS THAN</option>
                    <option value="&gt;=">GREATER THAN OR EQUAL TO</option>
                    <option value="&lt;=">LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO</option>
                </select></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="StudentInfo.Status-value" class="required" title="Value is required"></td>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="StudentInfo.Status-checkbox"></label></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I save the rows as JSON in the following format?, so that I can loop back over it to re-build the table rows, from the JSON.

```
columns: {
    StudentInfo.FirstName: {
       condition: 'CONTAINS',
       value: 'Carl'
    }
    StudentInfo.LastName: {
        condition: 'EQUALS',
        value: 'W'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Store it as a collection of array which you can loop through to rebuild the table html. This will reduce the memory usage also. And I think you should rename it as `rows` instead of `columns` because they are ideally rows of a table.

```
rows: [
    ['FirstName',  'CONTAINS',  'Carl'],
    ['LastName',  'EQUALS',  'W'],
];
```

Usage:

```
var $table = $('tableSelector');
$.each(rows, function(i, obj){
   //Now use obj which is again an array and create the required html
   $table.append(...);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for...Now just trying to figure out how to loop over the rows and get the values I need for each sub-array.

Comment: `obj[0] => "FirstName", obj[1] => "CONTAINS" ...` for first iteration. For better readability you could define constants named after your orignal JSON object fields: `NAME = 0, CONDITION = 1, VAL = 2` so you use `obj[VAL]`. (holds `"Carl"` in first step)

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will get your values into a JS object. I've not tested it though

```
 var tbody = $("#columnsTable tbody");

var StudentInfo = {
    "FirstName" : {
        "title" : "FirstName", 
        "condition" : tbody.find("select[id='StudentInfo.FirstName-condition'] option:selected").val(), 
        "value" : tbody.find("input[id='StudentInfo.FirstName-value']").val(), 
        "checked" : (tbody.find("input[id='StudentInfo.FirstName-checkbox']:checked").length > 0)
    }, 
    "LastName" : {
        "title" : "LastName", 
        "condition" : tbody.find("select[id='StudentInfo.LastName-condition'] option:selected").val(), 
        "value" : tbody.find("input[id='StudentInfo.LastName-value']").val(), 
        "checked" : (tbody.find("input[id='StudentInfo.LastName-checkbox']:checked").length > 0)
    }, 
    "CurrentCollege" : {
        "title" : "CurrentCollege", 
        "condition" : tbody.find("select[id='StudentInfo.CurrentCollege-condition'] option:selected").val(), 
        "value" : tbody.find("input[id='StudentInfo.CurrentCollege-value']").val(), 
        "checked" : (tbody.find("input[id='StudentInfo.CurrentCollege-checkbox']:checked").length > 0)
    }, 
    "EmailAddress" : {
        "title" : "EmailAddress", 
        "condition" : tbody.find("select[id='StudentInfo.EmailAddress-condition'] option:selected").val(), 
        "value" : tbody.find("input[id='StudentInfo.EmailAddress-value']").val(), 
        "checked" : (tbody.find("input[id='StudentInfo.EmailAddress-checkbox']:checked").length > 0)
    }, 
    "Status" : {
        "title" : "Status", 
        "condition" : tbody.find("select[id='StudentInfo.Status-condition'] option:selected").val(), 
        "value" : tbody.find("input[id='StudentInfo.Status-value']").val(), 
        "checked" : (tbody.find("input[id='StudentInfo.Status-checkbox']:checked").length > 0)
    },
};
```

Because you have used periods in the id and class names of your objects, I think jQuery is going to have a problem with that. I've used a selector in this above code that shouldn't have any issue with the periods.

**edit**

Fixed some selectors

**edit 2**

As far as using this: `alert(StudentInfo.CurrentCollege.condition);`.